# Is it possible to call a different class when a Button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, class, jbutton

So I have a window with a `JButton` called "start". What I would like to happen is when that button is clicked it will run a separate class I have already created.  Is this possible and if so how would I go about doing it?
Thanks for all your help

Here's what I have so far

```
JButton start = new JButton ("Play");
frame.add(start);
start.addActionListener(//not sure what goes here, i would like to call other class here)
```

By the way, the other class being called is falling in case that matters

Comment: Could you post what you have so far ?

Comment: I just did, theres a lot more but i think this is all that matters

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) is everything you need.

Comment: Essentially yes, but either your "other" class will need to implement `ActionListener` or your will need to provide a `ActionListener` capable of calling your "other" class.  Consider maybe using `Action`, [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Answer (score 3):

You(your class) can implement ActionListener to handle when the button is clicked.

```
public class YourClass implements ActionListener {

  public YourClass() {
    JButton start = new JButton ("Play");
    frame.add(start);
    start.addActionListener(this);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // Call other class
  }

}
```

Comment: Typo: The brace after constructor should be curly.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  If you want to use another class that has already implemented `ActionListener` then you can absolutely create an object of that class and then insert is as such:

```
//Another class that you're already created is named MyActionListener
// and implements ActionListener for this example

MyActionListener mal = new MyActionListener();
JButton start = new JButton ("Play");
frame.add(start);
start.addActionListener(mal);
```

However, this might not make any sense because you need to reference variables that are members of the current class's instance. In that case you want the current class to implement `ActionListener` as such:

```
class MyClass implements ActionListener {

    public MyClass() {
        JButton start = new JButton ("Play");
        frame.add(start);
        start.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //do whatever you need to do here
    }
}
```

The `this` keyword means that you are referring to the current instance of this class.  Therefore it will use the `actionPerformed` method that you implemented within this class.  You can instantiate an object of your other class within the `actionPerformed` method and then make any calls on that object as usual or if it's a member of this class, just call the member's function directly.  Additionally, if your referring to static methods on that second class you can also calls those directly within the `actionPerformed` method.

There is one other option, which is to use an anonymous inner class.  This is usually used if you want to have multiple `actionPerformed` methods within a single class that aren't shared between different components' event handler's registrations *(ie. just use it for this single start button)*.  Here's how to use that method:

```
JButton start = new JButton ("Play");
frame.add(start);
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //do whatever you want here for whenever start is clicked
    }
 });
```

As with the other options, you can also instantiate a second class in the `actionPerformed` method here or call a static method from another class.  However, if you were planning on calling a method that is on a variable that is a member of the outer class (`MyClass` in this case), then you need to use this syntax `this.MyOtherClass.method()`.  The reason being is that the `this` keyword in this case provides you with access to the outer class inside of the anonymous inner class.